# GWT AdsManager not displaying ads on map

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, adsense

Here's my code:

```
    AdsManagerOptions options = AdsManagerOptions.newInstance();
    options.setMaxAdsOnMap(1);      
    AdsManager ads = AdsManager.newInstance(map, "google");
    ads.setEnabled(true);
```

I tried doing this before the map is added to a panel, after a map is added to a panel, and any other way i could think of that could possibly make sense.  My publisher id is "google" because I havent been approved for adsense yet, but ive tried taking a real publisher id and i got the same result.

What is confusing me a bit, is that the AdsManager isnt a widget, so I cant choose where i want to place it on the map.  Ive read that this is actually how it works, but ive seen sites like http://mapper.acme.com/ where the ads are not in the typical bottom right corner.

Can someone PLEASE enlighten me on what I am doing wrong because this is driving me mad!  Thanks!

---

I still have no answer.  I am now trying with a legitimate publisher ID so I know that an invalid publisher id wasnt the reason for my frustrations.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that I absolutely need a valid publisher id before the box shows up on my map?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using firefox? If yes, do you have adblock on? Or any other adblocker on your browser?

Its also possible that the region you're looking at doesn't have any ads... Try zooming into a place like New York...